# Check if proxy is active

Tags: delphi-7

How can I test if for ex. 84.47.86.34:8080 is active proxy and is accepting requests.
Something like simple proxy check , that will tell me if proxy is valid.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to actually connect to the proxy, send it some data, and see if it replies.

Comment: I did so used Indy and if timeout occurred then proxy is inactive. I thought maybe there is a component that does that , but Indy will do. Thanks :)